# How can I compute $\lim_{t\to0} \cos(5t)$?

Tags: limits

> $$\lim_{t\to0} \cos(5t) = \, ?$$

Is there any difference between 
($i$) directly putting the value of $t$ in $\cos (5t)$ and 
($ii$) first changing $\cos (5t)$ as a function of $t$ and then putting the value of $t$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Have you just discussed that $\cos$ is a continuous function?

Comment: no, this is my first question.

Comment: No difference as long as you are careful with whatever you do in (ii). Obviously (i) is quicker. I'd like to know why you'd want to do (ii) : after all, $\cos (5t)$ is a function of $t$ , it's a composition of two functions given by multiplication by $5$, then the application of the cosine.

Comment: I want to know if the (i) is okay with all types of functions or if it is only for some particular kinds of functions like cos5t. Is there any function where (i) will not give the correct answer?

Comment: Context (i.e. the problem's background) is needed to accurately predict the solution intended by the problem composer.  This means that you need to focus on the theorems, worked examples, and previously solved problems (i.e. the **tools**) that led up to this problem, assuming that the problem is from a book or class.  ...see next comment

Comment: For example, have you been taught that [1] the cosine function is a continuous function for each real number? [2] That the function $f(x) = 5x$ is a continuous function? [3] That if $f,g$ are continuous functions, then so is $[g\circ f](x) = g[f(x)]$ (i.e. composition of continuous functions is continuous)?  If so, then the desired result is an immediate consequence of these preliminary results. ...see next comment

Comment: Alternatively, depending on the **tools** that led up to this problem, the problem composer may intend that you construct an $\epsilon, \delta$ type of demonstration.  If so, then you have the pending question whether you are (still) permitted to presume that (for example) the cosine function is itself a continuous function.  Alternatively, one might wonder if you have been exposed to the [Taylor Series for cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions).

Comment: As another alternative, it is (remotely) possible that you are responsible for knowing and using the identity that $$\cos(5t) = 16\cos^5(t) - 20\cos^3(t) + 5\cos(t).$$  Personally, I consider this last possibility remote, because then, the problem would not really have that much general educational value.